# How to enable focus on input element inside mat-select component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I need to activate the cursor on the html input element (search field) using keyboard inside mat-select.

It works perfectly fine when using mouse, but because of WCAG requirements I need to make it fully working using keyboard.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dukfxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I've tried almost everything from custom js code to Angular directives.

Any thougths?

[image]

Comment: Listen for up arrow and if the element with .mat-active is the first option, then input.focus()? Something like that

Comment: @MingleLi unfortunately does not work, I have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

#### 1. Add an identification to your input and use the event `openedChange` from mat-select

```
<mat-select (openedChange)="focus()">
  <input
    ...
    #exampleInput
   />
</mat-select>
```

#### 2. Define the function `focus()` in your component and it would work

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('exampleInput') searchElement: ElementRef;
  ...

  focus() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.searchElement.nativeElement.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nscqdp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Could you move that code to stackblitz to prove it works please?
I have added referance implementation in my post.

Comment: At the end, you can find the link